# Postgres aggregate json function to return array of objects with subquery

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables: patient, patient_form (join table), form that look as follows:

**patient**

```
| id  | name                |
| --- | ------------------- |
| 1   | Bob                 |
| 2   | Matilda             |
```

**patient_form (join table)**

```
| id  | patient_id | form_id |
| --- | ---------- | -------
| 1   | 1          |1
| 2   | 2          |1
```

**form**

```
| id  | label
| --- | ------------------- |
| 1   | intake              |
| 1   | follow up           |
```

I'd like to create a query that selects a patient and chains the relational data to result in the following output:

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: "Bob",
 forms: [ {label: "intake"}, {label:"followup"} ]
}
```

I understand that there a way using `json_agg` to create the desired array of objects unfortunatly I've not been able to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out as follows using `json_build_object`:

```
SELECT 
ARRAY(
    SELECT json_build_object(
        'link', link, 
        'label', (SELECT label FROM form WHERE id = form_id))
    FROM patient_form
    WHERE patient_form.patient_id = patient.id
    ) AS "forms"
WHERE patient.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the subquery for `forms`, you can use `JOIN` instead. The full implementation is as follows:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patient ( 
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  name TEXT NOT NULL 
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS form ( 
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  label TEXT NOT NULL 
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS patient_form( 
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
  patient_id INT, 
  form_id INT,
  CONSTRAINT patient_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(patient_id)
        REFERENCES patient(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT form_id_fk FOREIGN KEY(form_id)
        REFERENCES form(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
INSERT INTO form(id, label) VALUES (1, 'intake'), (2, 'follow up');
INSERT INTO patient(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Bob'), (2, 'Matilda');
INSERT INTO patient_form(id, patient_id, form_id) VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT json_build_object(
  'id', p.id,
  'name', p.name,
  'forms', json_agg(f)
) AS data
FROM patient AS p
JOIN patient_form AS p_f ON p_f.patient_id = p.id
JOIN form AS f ON f.id = p_f.form_id
WHERE p.id = 1
GROUP BY p.id;
```

| data |
| --- |
| {"id":1,"name":"Bob","forms":[{"id":1,"label":"intake"}]} |

---

Put simply, the output is:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Bob",
  "forms": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "label": "intake"
    }
  ]
}
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0)